# How do I run a function every four minutes since a specific epoch?

Tags: python

My main function calls a number of subroutines in a `while True:` loop.

I want to add another function `g()` that only runs once every four minutes. Function `g()` should only run at 4 minutes, 8 minutes, 12 minutes,  etc

I know I can check if a single amount of time has passed with `if epoch >= x`

But how do I run only `g()` every four minutes?

```
def main():
    epoch = time.time()
    count = 0 
    while True:        
        count = count + 1        
        if a() == 1:
            b()
            c()
            d()
            if count % 20:
                e()
            else:
                f()
            e()
            if epoch >= 240:
                g()
```

Edit; I can't run this as a separate thread as the answer in the duplicate suggested.

Comment: Off-topic: I suggest avoiding using a variable named `epoch` since it already has a very specific definition with respect to the [`time`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#module-time) module. Also see Wikipedia's [Epoch (computing)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(computing)) article.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new variable to store the next time the function should run:

```
import time
def main():
    epoch = time.time()
    count = 0
    next_g = 0
    while True:        
        count = count + 1        
        if a() == 1:
            b()
            c()
            d()
            if count % 20:
                e()
            else:
                f()
            e()
            if (epoch := time.time()) >= next_g:
                g()
                next_g = epoch + 240
```

Comment: g() is a function I use to close a particular application and it's running every single iteration of the loop rather than after 240s when I debug time.time() is starting at `1652681717.9829473` and even if I set next_g to 240 it's closing at every loop. Any thoughts?